# How can I use morris.js in React.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, morris.js

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Raphael from "raphael/raphael";
import "morris.js/morris.js";
import "morris.js/morris.css";

const Test = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.Raphael = Raphael;
    Morris.Donut({
      element: "test",
      data: [
        {
          label: "a",
          value: 49,
        },
        {
          label: "b",
          value: 51,
        },
      ],
      colors: ["#5f76e8", "#01caf1"],
      formatter: function (value, data) {
        return value + "%";
      },
    });
  }, []);
  return <div id="test" />;
};

export default Test;
```

I want to use morris.js in React.js.

But this code returns an error.

(Line 9:9:  'Morris' is not defined)

However, just before this error phrase appears, the pie chart is briefly visible, but soon the error phrase appears immediately.

How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach on this one. If the package you mentioned is type of `umd` or `commonjs` you can require to use directly:

```
const yourModule = import('morris.js/morris.js')
```

Or if you load your package as external such as CDN site, I assume you're now `webpack` as a bundler, then you just simply configure it in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
externals : {
 morris: "Morris"
},
```

And in your html template `index.html` would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
```

Then you just simply import to use in your module:

```
import morris from "morris"
```